# Where do I put admobs .Jar file in Flash Pro CS5.5?

Tags: actionscript-3, admob, flash-cs5, flash-cs5.5

I have created an app in Flash CS5.5 and would like to put admobs advertisements in it.

I am having problems figuring out where to put the .jar file that comes with admobs.

All the tutorials say put it in "build path", but there is no build path option in Flash Pro CS5.5

Flash Develop and I are not on good terms right now, and I am currently using Sublime Text 2 for coding all of the as3 and xml.

Can someone give some advice on how to get this working with the programs I am using?

Comment: you can see,
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22076591/how-to-show-admob-ads-ios-and-android-through-actionscript-in-flash-cc/27467442#27467442

Answer (score 0):

JAR files are for Java applications and will not work with Actionscript.

Depending on the platform that you are targeting you will have to choose an alternative way to deploy AdMobs. For instance, if you are trying to use AdMobs on an AIR app targeting Android or iOS you can use an ANE (AIR Native Extension) such as [this one](http://lancelotmobile.com/blog/admob-ane/).

Comment: The link you put here goes to a .ane file. Flash CS5.5 is only letting me add .swc files. What do i do with this ane file?

I see options for library path and source path, but not the mysterious "build path"

Comment: @Jim Rename the .ane file to .swc and add to library path (build path is for Adobe Flash Builder but you are using Flash Pro). Check out [this article](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/air/build/WS597e5dadb9cc1e0253f7d2fc1311b491071-8000.html) for the full steps of how to incorporate ANE.